# Why geopandas.read_file returns different result on windows and linux?

Tags: python, linux, shapefile, geopandas

I'm using geopandas to read a .shp file. My code is like the following:

```
import geopandas as gpd

blocks = gpd.read_file('shp/block_shp/block.shp', encoding = 'utf-8')
print(blocks.columns)
```

On my windows machine, the output (the columns of the geopandas dataframe) is this:

```
Index(['ID', 'AREA', 'ID1', 'AREA1', 'NAME', 'DISTRICT', 'BLOCK_ID','geometry'],
  dtype='object')
```

I copied the same code and the folder containing the `.shp` file to the linux machine (centos 7) and run the code. No error or warning occured, but the printed result is different:

```
Index(['geometry'], dtype='object')
```

It only get the last column `geometry` and miss all the other columns. The reading process is much faster than that on windows and I wonder if it did miss those columns while reading. The depending packages version on windows machine are the following:

`pip show show GDAL fiona rtree pyproj shapely geopandas`

```
Name: GDAL
Version: 2.3.3
Summary: GDAL: Geospatial Data Abstraction Library
Home-page: http://www.gdal.org
Author: Frank Warmerdam
Author-email: warmerdam@pobox.com
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
---
Name: Fiona
Version: 1.8.4
Summary: Fiona reads and writes spatial data files
Home-page: http://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona
Author: Sean Gillies
Author-email: sean.gillies@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires: attrs, munch, click, click-plugins, cligj, six
Required-by:
---
Name: Rtree
Version: 0.8.3
Summary: R-Tree spatial index for Python GIS
Home-page: http://toblerity.github.com/rtree/
Author: Sean Gillies
Author-email: sean.gillies@gmail.com
License: LGPL
Location: c:\users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires: setuptools
Required-by:
---
Name: pyproj
Version: 1.9.6
Summary: Python interface to PROJ.4 library
Home-page: https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj
Author: Jeff Whitaker
Author-email: jeffrey.s.whitaker@noaa.gov
License: OSI Approved
Location: c:\users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: geopandas
---
Name: Shapely
Version: 1.6.4.post1
Summary: Geometric objects, predicates, and operations
Home-page: https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely
Author: Sean Gillies
Author-email: sean.gillies@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
---
Name: geopandas
Version: 0.4.0
Summary: Geographic pandas extensions
Home-page: http://geopandas.org
Author: GeoPandas contributors
Author-email: kjordahl@alum.mit.edu
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires: fiona, pyproj, shapely, pandas
Required-by:
```

And the packages version on linux:

`pip3 show GDAL fiona rtree pyproj shapely geopandas`

```
Name: GDAL
Version: 2.3.3
Summary: GDAL: Geospatial Data Abstraction Library
Home-page: http://www.gdal.org
Author: Frank Warmerdam
Author-email: warmerdam@pobox.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
---
Name: Fiona
Version: 1.8.4
Summary: Fiona reads and writes spatial data files
Home-page: http://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona
Author: Sean Gillies
Author-email: sean.gillies@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: six, munch, cligj, click-plugins, attrs, click
Required-by:
---
Name: Rtree
Version: 0.8.3
Summary: R-Tree spatial index for Python GIS
Home-page: http://toblerity.github.com/rtree/
Author: Howard Butler
Author-email: hobu@hobu.net
License: LGPL
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: setuptools
Required-by:
---
Name: pyproj
Version: 1.9.6
Summary: Python interface to PROJ.4 library
Home-page: https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj
Author: Jeff Whitaker
Author-email: jeffrey.s.whitaker@noaa.gov
License: OSI Approved
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: geopandas
---
Name: Shapely
Version: 1.6.4
Summary: Geometric objects, predicates, and operations
Home-page: https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely
Author: Sean Gillies
Author-email: sean.gillies@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
---
Name: geopandas
Version: 0.4.0
Summary: Geographic pandas extensions
Home-page: http://geopandas.org
Author: GeoPandas contributors
Author-email: kjordahl@alum.mit.edu
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: pandas, shapely, fiona, pyproj
Required-by:
```

I don't know why this happened. Could someone tell me how to fix this problem? Thank you for your attention.

The result of running `fio info --indent 2 path_to_shp` gives different results:

windows:

```
{
  "driver": "ESRI Shapefile",
  "schema": {
    "properties": {
      "ID": "int:10",
      "AREA": "float:10.2",
      "ID1": "int:10",
      "AREA1": "float:10.6",
      "NAME": "str:16",
      "DISTRICT": "str:16",
      "BLOCK_ID": "int:8"
    },
    "geometry": "Polygon"
  },
  "crs": "EPSG:4326",
  "crs_wkt": "GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]]",
  "bounds": [
    113.75219,
    22.447622,
    114.6233,
    22.86469
  ],
  "name": "block",
  "count": 74
}
```

linux:

```
{
  "driver": "ESRI Shapefile",
  "schema": {
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": "Polygon"
  },
  "crs": "EPSG:4326",
  "crs_wkt": "GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.HORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]]",
  "bounds": [
    113.75219,
    22.447622,
    114.6233,
    22.86469
  ],
  "name": "block",
  "count": 74
}
```

And I'm sure the other files (.DBF, .prj, .shx and .geojson) are all the same within the folder of .shp file.

Comment: Can you check with the fiona command line (https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona#fiona-cli) the structure of the file in both places? Something like `fio info --indent 2 path/to/shapefile.shp`. And you are sure to have copied all accompanying files of the .shp file as well?

Comment: Hi @joris. I followed your advice and updated the result in my post.

Comment: This happens if you load shapefile without .dbf file. I've just replicated your issue. I guess joris is correct with his last sentence. Have you checked that?

Comment: @martinfleis I don't have .dbf file on my windows machine as well. Why it works on windows?

Comment: Well, it should not work on windows :D. .dbf is one of three mandatory files, the only one storing attributes. Without .dbf, 1) shapefile is invalid, 2) you should have only geometry. I have no clue why it loads attributes on windows if there is no source file for them as you say.